# Monotonicity of Integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have problems with the following task:

Let $I \subset \mathbb R $ be an unpredicted interval, and let $F, G: I \to \mathbb R$ be continuously differentiable.

$F'(x) \leq G'(x) $ for all $x \in I$ and there is an $a \in I$ with $F(a) \leq G(a)$.
Prove, that for all $x \in I$ with $x \geq a$, $F(x) \leq G(x)$ is also valid.

Do you have ideas how to prove that?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "unpredicted"?

Comment: Are you still here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

*Mean value theorem* applied to $F-G$.